# Set formula into a cell based on content of another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange, google-sheets-arrayformula

Google Sheets:

I would like to set a formula into a cell,  but this should depend on content of another cell.

**Example Google Sheet (anybody can edit):**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z2VVLH5saVKJQ97xUNTZ4vssXnw9Q_ruyQF61tCbxsU/edit?usp=sharing

**Goal (old):**

The RED "aaa" cell change should set the BLUE "changeme" content to

- "aaa", if "aaa"
- "", if "nothing"
- "=ROUNDUP((1+2)/2)", if "myformula"
- "=SUM(1+2)", if "myformula2"

**EDIT1:**

To make the definition clearer, I created a new worksheet "sheet_new (editable)" on the example Google Sheet:

**Goal (new):**

The RED cell change should set the BLUE content to:

- Formula, if RED cell is set to Automatic
- Empty cell, if RED cell is set to Manual

I hope it is clearer now.

Probably using importrange or arrayformula would be the solution.

**EDIT2:**

If RED cell is set to Manual the user can enter numbers manually to BLUE cell. If RED cell is set to Automatic, the value of BLUE cell will be a formula, which calculates the value.

Comment: Please change the permissions on your sheet to "Anyone with the link can Edit" (not just View), and I or someone else here can better help you.

Comment: Ok, allowed to edit.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the formula I supplied:

`=IFS(B3="aaa","aaa",B3="nothing","",B3="myformula",ROUNDUP((1+2)/2),B3="myformula2",SUM(1+2))`

It should be pretty easy to understand (i.e., condition, result, condition, result, etc.).

Comment: Unfortunately with this method, I will always have a formula in RED cell, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Likely ArrayFormula or ImportRange will be the solution, combined with IFS condition.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Unfortunately with this method, I will always have a formula in RED cell, which is what I want to avoid." There is no formula in the red cell; the formula would go in the blue cell.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The correct sentence would be the following: "Unfortunately with this method, I will always have a formula in BLUE cell, which is what I want to avoid.". The BLUE cell would have two functions. 1) Automatic value calculation with formula 2) Manual value entering, which needs no formula, just an empty cell. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Edited question and added a new example Google Sheet.

Comment: It sounds like what you're saying is that you want the option of whether the blue cell will hold a string value or a formula; but that is the default functionality of any cell: if you enter a string, it's a string and if you enter a formula, it's a formula. Perhaps it would be best if you actually showed a few examples in your sheet: "If this is set this way, I want this here to happen."

Comment: I did show a new example. It shows exactly what I need, Manual or Automatic formula. If it is set to Manual the user can enter numbers manually. If it is set to Automatic, the value of BLUE cell will be a formula, which calculates the value.

Comment: Klor, I would recommend that you repost your question as you see fit. Hopefully, you'll attract the attention of another expert who understands you better than I can. Good luck.